# MVC 5.0 RegisterRoutes not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Anyone know why this is not working, i have googled it but nothing seems to work. All i want to do is allow www.abcdefg.com/username to map to a profile page but it does not work and i can't find out why.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
         routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",                                              // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        , new { controller = @"(admin|help|profile|Settings)" } // Constraints
    );
                routes.MapRoute(
                  "Users",
                  "{username}",
                  new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", username = "" });
            }
```

Comment: Have you tested to see if localhost/Home/Index/username works? I will start with that. In other words, do you have a controller action called Index, in controller Home that accepts a string parameter labeled username?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must adding the default route as the **last route**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
         routes.MapRoute(
           "Users",
           "{username}",
           new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", username = "" });

         routes.MapRoute(
           "Default",                                              // Route name
           "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
           new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
           , new { controller = @"(admin|help|profile|Settings)" } // Constraints
    );
```